# Using Subversion, how can you tell if all the files in a particular hard-drive folder have been checked-in and committed to the repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

With Source Safe, after I add files to Source Control, they are set read-only locally.  So then if I go to Explorer, and check the contents, I can quickly see which files didn't get into source control, because they are still read-write.

With SVN, the software doesn't mark the local files as read-only after check-in, which is fine, but when initially adding an unknown Visual Studio project to SVN, Visual Studio obviously only adds those files that are in its solution.  Some supporting files, such as documentation, etc., may be in the source folder, but not added as an item in Visual Studio, so Visual Studio won't add those files.  I'll have to manually add them, or I can add those files to Visual Studio's solution, and have Visual Studio do it.   But either way, I still need a way to determine which files were not added.

I tried the Lock feature, but that didn't make a difference as far as the local read-only flag of the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try svn status at the root of the directory you're checking.  More info "svn help status".

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Tortoise? Use "Check for Modifications" or "Commit" and in the dialog that comes up, make sure that "Show unversioned files" is checked.

Answer (score 2):

`svn st` will show a question mark in front of files that aren't under version control.

Answer (score 0):

Use [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) or [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), with [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: These will supply you with some GUI tools, as well as put icon indicators right in Windows Explorer and Visual Studios so you will know the status of each of your files just by glancing at them.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice the limitation of `svn st`. Suppose you added a new library `test.a` in your library, see what you will get by `svn get`:

```
root@pierr-desktop:/lib# svn st
M      VDL.a
M      libtoshiba_tuner.a
root@pierr-desktop:/lib# >test.a      #create test.a in local copy
root@pierr-desktop:/lib# snv st       #svn st can not detect the newly add test.a file
M      VDL.a
M      libtoshiba_tuner.a
```

use `svn st --no-ignore` to overcome this.

```
root@pierr-desktop:/lib# svn st --no-ignore
I      test.a                         #list the ignored file
M      VDL.a
M      libtoshiba_tuner.a
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "added a new library test.a in your library".

Also what is the command ">test.a" ?

I created a dummy file in the folder (a text file), and svn -st saw it.  what is the --no-ignore for here?